# An application I made automatically starts on my computer, and I can't find where to disable it

Tags: windows-10, boot

I made an application to connect to an Arduino i2c keyboard to make my own shortcuts on a different keyboard. I have since replaced it, but it still starts the controller when I start my computer.
The program starts before I log in. There is nothing inside the shell:startup folder.
If I remember correctly I used some tool inside of windows to start it automatically, but I can't find the tutorial or the tool anywhere.

[This is what appears when I start my computer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2LpN.png)

Comment: Autoruns from sysinternals/Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns is s really nice for tracking down things like this

Answer (score 0):

The [tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) mentioned by [Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek), works really well. After using the tool I saw that it was being started by the windows task scheduler, where I was able to disable it.